# Date format in Informatica expression

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-data-integration-hub

In Informatica I use the below expression:

```
IIF( PARAMETER_NAME='$$CURRENT_DATE_IN_SQL_FORMAT',TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'PARAMETER_VALUE')
```

which give me the date in format `2021-11-25`

But I need it me to return value as below format

```
TO_DATE('2021-11-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Any help is much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use below expression.

```
IIF( PARAMETER_NAME='$$CURRENT_DATE_IN_SQL_FORMAT',
'TO_DATE('|| CHR(39)||
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')||chr(39)||','||chr(39)||'YYYY-MM-DD'||chr(39)||')',
,'PARAMETER_VALUE')
```

You can calculate your expected output by concatenating quote, and ||.